# privoxy show client ip when sending mail

Tags: email, ip, proxy, privoxy

Is it possible for `privoxy` to show original client ip when sending mail ( example:
this mail header should show the client's ip not the proxy ip:

```
Received: from [xx.xx.xx.xx] by web142501.mail.bf1.yahoo.com via HTTP;
```

I found that this

```
{ +change-x-forwarded-for{add} }
```

will detect the proxy ip and also the client's ip but does not seem to work with mail headers.

Answer (score 1):

The `Received:` header you post is added by Yahoo's webmail server. The only IP it's going to ever see is the proxy's. The email headers are generated by the webmail, as far as I know, there's no way for you to influence this.

If you wanted to add the headers yourself, you'd have to use a mail user agent (a mail client) instead of using the webmail. In this case the headers would be generated on your side and you could add anything you want. You would then send the email to Yahoo!'s SMTP server.